# Can containerized windows console app add message to host MSMQ

Tags: containers, msmq, windows-container

Containers (Docker,etc) are awesome and I am excited on the possibilities it has to offer. My application uses the following (all installed on windows host machine)

1. Sql Server
2. MSMQ
3. Multiple Console apps end points: to read and write to MSMQ
4. Website

Now I am planning to containerize the following (windows containers)

1. Multiple Console apps
2. Website

I am **not looking to containarize MSMQ and SQL Server** at the moment and these will be installed on the host machine as before.

I am able to create images and run it as containers using Docker Engine. But they are all running in isolation. They need to interact with the host machine. I am not able to figure that out.

Now after reading lots of articles on the net, I still don't have a valid answer to the following

1. Can containerized end points (console apps in my case) add messages to HOST MSMQ?
2. Can containerized console apps end points read messages from HOST MSMQ?
3. I have read that containerized apps (console in my case) can read and write to SQL server installed on host machine, this is true right?

I am able to create images, run it as containers but these cross linking parts I am not able to figure it out and not getting any conclusive links on the internet, can someone help me out.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

yes, yes and yes... they can communicate...

The tricky part is to understand that your apps running inside a container in your host are seeing like apps in your host. Which means that if you fire up a service on port 5555 in your container, you can access it by calling localhost:5555 (if 5555 is not taken in the host, otherwise you need to set the -p flag when running the container).

But, when running inside the container... your host is seen as a computer over the network so you need to access it via their common network IP address.

I'm not saying that the only way, that's just the way I know and it works!

Edit: I just happened to find this article you might find useful, not mine. [Working with MSMQ in Windows Docker Containers](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1278439/Working-with-MSMQ-in-Windows-Docker-Containers)